# Image style changing does not work in view with migrated image fields

Tags: 7, views, migrations, media

As part of migration I have image fields that have been migrated. I have views those use that image fields, but changing image styles cause nothing!

I can edit image style and its working correctly as it show previews. Views seems to be ignoring image styles and taking original images always.

Can somebody help?

Thanks

Comment: I don't understand what you have done with your image fields. What does "migrated" mean? Is the working preview in Views, or somewhere else?

Comment: @Letharion 'Migrated' means it is migrated from D6 CCK field to D7 using CCK migration module. Preview working in 'edit image style' and not in 'edit view'.